# How can I solve non linear system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following system of equations

```
E1 = Sin[u[1]] + 24.99741937197641*(-0.2 + u[1]);
E2 = Sin[u[2]] + 24.99741937197641*(0.00006931712037649973*(-0.2 + u[1]) + 1.*(-2*u[1] + u[2]));
NSolve[{E1 == 0, E2 == 0}, {u[1], u[2]}]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FindRoot`,

```
FindRoot[{E1 == 0, E2 == 0}, {u[1], 0}, {u[2], 0}]
```

> {u[1] -> 0.192352, u[2] -> 0.370231}